# How to retrieve imageid and insert it into another table? (Mysqli)

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I have a mysqli code below where it uploads a file and insert data into the "Image" Table:

```
<?php

session_start();


$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="mobile_app";

  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

$result = 0;

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
    VALUES (?)";

            if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($imagesql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

    //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s",$img);

//Assign the variable
$img = 'ImageFiles/'.$_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

 $insert->execute();

      }

  }



?>
```

So for example if I insert 2 images "cat.png" and "dog.png" into "Image" Database table, it will insert it like this:

```
ImageId         ImageFile

220             cat.png
221             dog.png
```

(ImageId is an auto increment)

Anyway what my question is that when a file is uploaded, not only is the data inserted into the table above, but I want to also be able to retrieve the ImageId that was inserted above and place it in the Image_Question table below so it would be like this:

```
 ImageId         SessionId      QuestionId

    220             cat.png      1
    221             dog.png      4
```

MY question is that how do I retrieve the ImageId from the Image Table and insert it into the Image_Question Table? Below is my code which will insert data into the Image_Question table using mysql, just need to be able to retrieve the ImageId from the Image Table:

```
 $imagequestionsql = "INSERT INTO Image_Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


        if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestionsql)) {
          // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        }

    $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');

    $insertimagequestion->bind_param("sss", $sessid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i]);

            $insertimagequestion->execute();

            if ($insertimagequestion->errno) {
              // Handle query error here
            }

            $insertimagequestion->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first insert, you can use [mysqli_insert_id](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id) to get the id, and the use that when you do the second insert into Image_Question.